# How to display Highcharts in rows (5)

Tags: css

I am new to CSS , so please excuse if this is a dumb question .

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7cvCX/157/

I need to dsplay 10 charts in my page .

Right now its displaying one after another .

Please let me how can i display 5 in one row and another 5 in next row ??

This is my HTML CODE

```
<div id="chart-A" class="chart"></div> 
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div id="chart-B" class="chart"></div> 
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div id="chart-C" class="chart"></div> 
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div id="chart-D" class="chart"></div> 
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div id="chart-E" class="chart"></div> 
<div class="spacer"></div>



.chart {
    height: 150px;
}
```

Could you please let me know how can i display charts in two rows ??(Each row consisting of 5 .)

Comment: Ya i wanted to keep the fiddle simple , so only pasted 5 charts , the same will be the code for another 5 .

Comment: Already there are 5 chart bars in a row. I can't understand.

Comment: This is my updated fiddle to add more charts http://jsfiddle.net/7cvCX/158/

Comment: You want 5 charts in one column and next 5 in another right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the first 5 charts in a column and other 5 in another column. Set a width for the columns. Float the 1st column left for the 2nd column to flow around the right space.

```css
.chart {
  height: 150px;
}
.col-1 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  max-width: 50%;
}
.col-2 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-1">
  <div id="chart-A" class="chart"></div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div id="chart-B" class="chart"></div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div id="chart-C" class="chart"></div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div id="chart-D" class="chart"></div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div id="chart-E" class="chart"></div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-2">
  <div id="chart-F" class="chart"></div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div id="chart-G" class="chart"></div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/7cvCX/159/)

[image: 2 column charts]

Comment: Thank you , but still i see charts one after another only (the height of the charts is reduced)

Comment: Can you post an example output of how you would like it? I can't find what you need.